# How to implement an empty path in YAML file

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger

I am trying to implement the below calls:

POST https://host/sessions

DELETE https://host/sessions/{session_id}

The POST call is to establish a session, the DELETE call is to log out an established session.

So, in the YAML file, how to have an empty base path? It's currently a slash in the YAML file as it's a required filed, but the slash is redundant.  Any idea? Thanks.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '0.0.1'
  title: authenticate
  #description: To be provided
  #  #termsOfService:To be provided
  contact:
   name: test
basePath:  /sessions 
paths:
  /:
    post:
      summary: eatablish a session
      description: sessions is a collection.This POST creates a new session in the sessions collection and the name of the session returned by this command is the session token.
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: user_name
          type: string
          required: true
        - in: header
          name: password
          type: string
          required: true          
      responses:
        200:
          description: establish a session successfully
        400:
          $ref: "#/responses/BadRequest"
        500:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/errorModel'
            
  /{session_id}:
    delete:
      summary: log out
      description: use sessionid to log out an established session.
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: session_id
          type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: log out a session successfully
        400:
          $ref: "#/responses/BadRequest"
        500:
          description: unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/errorModel'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger [defines](https://swagger.io/specification/#pathsObject)

> A relative path to an individual endpoint. The field name MUST begin with a forward slash (`/`).

Therefore, the slash is required and you can't have an empty path.

Comment: Thanks, so it means the URI has to be POST https://host/sessions//, not POST https://host/sessions, right?

Comment: Well you can always use `basePath: /` and then have `/sessions` and `/sessions/{session_id}` as paths. The idea is that all paths must be inside the base path, and the base path itself is not (while `/` is). I am unsure whether the query would work without trailing slash as it is; however you can always configure your web server to forward it.